# How to "casting the argument to 'dart.ui::Image'" in Flutter/Dart

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I want to show Image widget in flutter using RawImage

```
RawImage(Image);
```

I am using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image to 
create an Image object using

```
ImageX = decodeImage('List<int> data')
```

Its showing this error:

> Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to
>   'dart.ui::Image'
>
> error: The argument type '**Image**
>   (/Users/xxx/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart)'
>   can't be assigned to the parameter type '**Image**
>   (/Users/xxx/dev/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/painting.dart)'.

How can I Solve this?

Is there a way to change the type of ImageX to '**Image**(/Users/xxx/dev/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/painting.dart)'

for example -

```
Image ImageX = (IM.decodeImage(document['bn'])) as Image //error
```

Comment: Why are you using the image package? Wouldn't you use `Image.memory` which would get you straight to a Widget? (Or `Image.asset` or `Image.network` if the source is an asset or network resource?)

Comment: I am using image package to create a thumbnail img then push it to firestore document as List<int> so when I want to show to that thumbnail img, I am decoding image and trying to show using RawImage, its mess. any better way?

Comment: Use the image package to make the thumbnail and convert it to PNG, save that as List<int>, when you read it back as List<int> use `Image.memory`

Comment: ok, trying that..

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for the help.